# Master Pages using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: 2016, visual-studio-2017

Trying to build a SharePoint master page in the new Visual Studio 2017 but doesn't seem to have an option to add just a master page.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that whilst custom master pages are still viable and will be supported Microsoft do NOT recommend them for SP online / on premises.

Their reasoning behind this is due to continued updated to online which would be lost on custom master pages. You loose out on new rolled out content, cumulative update for security etc...

You can still work around it by using the suggestion above but they just don't recommend it.

They suggest you use JS injection & Custom theme/look & feel. Which is rubbish if you ask me!

Comment: Is your answer related to your question? could you please share a screenshot for creating a master page in Visual Studio 2017 ??!!!

Comment: there is already a spolution above on how to create and my explanation points out the reasoning WHY it isn't as simple as a template you can use.

Comment: Not true. This was not your question you have said **Any suggestions on where to start?** to create a master page, not why it's not a simple template, So you should appreciate the correct answers and don't add answer that is not related to the question to avoid deleting answer !

Comment: lol read the question again. I said I couldn't find a template to create a master page and wanted some direction - the next response shows a way on HOW to create one - which was useful! but didn't explain the logic behind why there isn't a template for it inbuilt. My answer above explains the logic and reasoning that Microsoft have given for not having a template. That's all

Comment: I don' care about this, we just here to help. but it's the SE rules, the answer should be related to your question? Did you mentioned you need to know the logic behind why there isn't a template for it inbuilt in your question !!!!! I think you must read your question again to know you said this or not?!

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware of

> There is no item called `Master page` in visual studio 2012/ 2013 / 2015 /2017.
>   To create a custom master page using visual studio, you should add a **Module**

**Crete Master Page using VS Steps:**

- Create an empty SharePoint farm solution.
- Right click on your project > Add > New Item.
- Add Module from the Add New Item window > Rename it as you like “MasterPages”.

[image]

- Rename the Sample.txt file as MyMasterPage.master.
- Open the existing SharePoint site in SharePoint Designer 2013.
- Go to All Files -> _catalog -> master pages.
- Open the v4.master file. Copy this file content and place in our
- Do modification as per your requirement in the MyMasterPage.master.

Check detail Steps at [Create Custom Master Page In SharePoint Using Visual Studio](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/)